# github failed to clone repo on windows

Tags: windows, github

Github failed to clone repo on windows. 
I have tried to delete the entire directory and clone again but still the same error. It works in other OS like linux and Mac. I checked if it is because file path is too long or if it has windows incompatible characters. But error says .git doesn't point at a valid Git repository or workdir?
Most of the code still gets cloned over but the main error seems to be

```
LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryNotFoundException: Path 'G:\GitHub\CSE340cpp\.git' doesn't point at a valid Git repository or workdir.
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options)
   at GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel.CreateRepositoryForConnection()
   at GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel.<>c__DisplayClass7c`2.<RunConnectionOperation>b__75()
2017-10-24 13:28:22.4454|INFO|thread:19|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 1 at GitClient.cs:605 after blocking 0.0461216s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.4454|INFO|thread: 8|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired exclusive scheduler for operation: 2 at GitClient.cs:583 after waiting 0.0450649s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.4454|WARN|thread: 8|RepositoryModel|exclusive connection for GitClient.cs:583 signalled RepositoryNotFoundException. Marked repository as lost on disk.
LibGit2Sharp.RepositoryNotFoundException: Path 'G:\GitHub\CSE340cpp\.git' doesn't point at a valid Git repository or workdir.
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open(String path)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository..ctor(String path, RepositoryOptions options)
   at GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel.CreateRepositoryForConnection()
   at GitHub.Models.RepositoryModel.<>c__DisplayClass7c`2.<RunConnectionOperation>b__75()
2017-10-24 13:28:22.4454|WARN|thread: 8|DashboardViewModel|Could not fix bad proxy setting as the repository does not exist.
2017-10-24 13:28:22.4454|INFO|thread: 8|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released exclusive scheduler for operation: 2 at GitClient.cs:583 after blocking 0.0058503s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.5980|INFO|thread:11|SshProcessManager|Starting ssh-agent.exe
2017-10-24 13:28:22.5980|INFO|thread:11|PortablePackageManager|Already extracted lfs-amd64.7z, returning 100%
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6365|INFO|thread:15|DashboardViewModel|Selected repository 'echosys/CSE330c'
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6365|INFO|thread:15|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 3 at GitClient.cs:605
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6365|INFO|thread:15|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring exclusive scheduler for operation 4 at GitClient.cs:583
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6365|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 3 at GitClient.cs:605 after waiting 0.0002178s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6775|INFO|thread:10|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 3 at GitClient.cs:605 after blocking 0.0403648s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.6775|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired exclusive scheduler for operation: 4 at GitClient.cs:583 after waiting 0.0404997s
2017-10-24 13:28:22.8880|INFO|thread:28|GitEnvironment|Process set up with this SSH Agent info: 7136:/tmp/ssh-klrBWqcAJASj/agent.1820
2017-10-24 13:28:22.8880|INFO|thread:28|GitEnvironment|PATH is F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\share\git-tfs;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\R88BMX93.5ZB\4QNCR5ZP.PEG\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0003_5794af8169eeff14;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\lfs-amd64_1.5.5;F:\Windows\System32;F:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\;F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64
2017-10-24 13:28:22.8945|INFO|thread:28|ProcessWrapper|Starting: Process - FileName: 'F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin\ssh-add.exe', Args: '"F:\Users\Jean_Claude\.ssh\github_rsa"', Working Directory: F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\Temp\
2017-10-24 13:28:23.0325|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 5 at GitClient.cs:600
2017-10-24 13:28:23.1570|WARN|thread:19|DashboardViewModel|Repository 'CSE340cpp' is missing from disk - throwing a user error.
```

The more error code is below

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 21
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: CA13:33EA:5323DBE:7442473:59EFA2A8
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com/echosys/CSE340cpp.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host github.com: 0xce60d0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host github.com
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user '[redacted]'
> GET /echosys/CSE340cpp.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
Authorization: Basic [redacted]
User-Agent: git/2.11.0.windows.3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 21
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitHub"
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: CA13:33EA:5323DCF:744248E:59EFA2A8
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
13:29:33.180468 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'github --credentials store'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host github.com: 0xce60d0 [can pipeline]
* NTLM-proxy picked AND auth done set, clear picked!
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* Hostname github.com was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.253.112...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle-ghfw.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=5157550; street=88 Colin P Kelly, Jr Street; postalCode=94107; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*  start date: Mar 10 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*  expire date: May 17 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "github.com" matched cert's "github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'b7d881bfd1412bb946280eca716fa19050e9f1c2'
> GET /echosys/CSE340cpp.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
Authorization: Basic [redacted]
User-Agent: git/2.11.0.windows.3
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: CA15:33E9:3D30E78:57142FE:59EFA2A9
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
13:29:34.416625 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--thin' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--cloning' 'https://github.com/echosys/CSE340cpp.git/'
13:29:34.430627 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--thin' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--cloning' 'https://github.com/echosys/CSE340cpp.git/'
remote: Counting objects: 394, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:  10% (1/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  20% (2/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  30% (3/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  40% (4/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  50% (5/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  60% (6/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  70% (7/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  80% (8/10)           
remote: Compressing objects:  90% (9/10)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10)           
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.        
13:29:34.651655 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 6200 on Jean_Claude-PC' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--pack_header=2,394'
13:29:34.665657 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'index-pack' '--stdin' '-v' '--fix-thin' '--keep=fetch-pack 6200 on Jean_Claude-PC' '--check-self-contained-and-connected' '--pack_header=2,394'
Receiving objects:   0% (1/394)   
Receiving objects:   1% (4/394)   
Receiving objects:   2% (8/394)   
Receiving objects:   3% (12/394)   
Receiving objects:   4% (16/394)   
Receiving objects:   5% (20/394)   
Receiving objects:   6% (24/394)   
Receiving objects:   7% (28/394)   
Receiving objects:   8% (32/394)   
Receiving objects:   9% (36/394)   
Receiving objects:  10% (40/394)   
Receiving objects:  11% (44/394)   
Receiving objects:  12% (48/394)   
Receiving objects:  13% (52/394)   
Receiving objects:  14% (56/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  15% (60/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  16% (64/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  17% (67/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  18% (71/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  19% (75/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  20% (79/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  21% (83/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  22% (87/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  23% (91/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  24% (95/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  25% (99/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  26% (103/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  27% (107/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  28% (111/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  29% (115/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  30% (119/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  31% (123/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  32% (127/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  33% (131/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  34% (134/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  35% (138/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  36% (142/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  37% (146/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  38% (150/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  39% (154/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  40% (158/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  41% (162/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  42% (166/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  43% (170/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  44% (174/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  45% (178/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  46% (182/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  47% (186/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  48% (190/394), 212.01 KiB | 406.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  48% (190/394), 572.01 KiB | 555.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  49% (194/394), 836.01 KiB | 543.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  49% (196/394), 836.01 KiB | 543.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  50% (197/394), 1.29 MiB | 497.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  50% (197/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  51% (201/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  52% (205/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  53% (209/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  54% (213/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  55% (217/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  56% (221/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  57% (225/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  58% (229/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  59% (233/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  60% (237/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  61% (241/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  62% (245/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  63% (249/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  64% (253/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  65% (257/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  66% (261/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  67% (264/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  68% (268/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  69% (272/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  70% (276/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  71% (280/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  72% (284/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  73% (288/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  74% (292/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  75% (296/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  76% (300/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  77% (304/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  78% (308/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  79% (312/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  80% (316/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  81% (320/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  82% (324/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  83% (328/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  84% (331/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  85% (335/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  86% (339/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  87% (343/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  88% (347/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  89% (351/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  90% (355/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  91% (359/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  92% (363/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (367/394), 1.62 MiB | 510.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (370/394), 1.86 MiB | 428.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (370/394), 2.04 MiB | 405.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (370/394), 2.07 MiB | 305.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (370/394), 2.17 MiB | 262.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  93% (370/394), 2.28 MiB | 221.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  94% (371/394), 2.57 MiB | 224.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  94% (372/394), 2.88 MiB | 244.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  94% (373/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  95% (375/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  96% (379/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  97% (383/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  98% (387/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  99% (391/394), 3.11 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s   
remote: Total 394 (delta 0), reused 8 (delta 0), pack-reused 383        
Receiving objects: 100% (394/394), 3.32 MiB | 233.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects: 100% (394/394), 3.32 MiB | 252.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:   0% (0/142)   
Resolving deltas:  10% (15/142)   
Resolving deltas:  12% (18/142)   
Resolving deltas:  14% (20/142)   
Resolving deltas:  15% (22/142)   
Resolving deltas:  16% (23/142)   
Resolving deltas:  17% (25/142)   
Resolving deltas:  18% (26/142)   
Resolving deltas:  19% (27/142)   
Resolving deltas:  26% (37/142)   
Resolving deltas:  27% (39/142)   
Resolving deltas:  30% (44/142)   
Resolving deltas:  31% (45/142)   
Resolving deltas:  35% (50/142)   
Resolving deltas:  36% (52/142)   
Resolving deltas:  37% (53/142)   
Resolving deltas:  38% (55/142)   
Resolving deltas:  39% (56/142)   
Resolving deltas:  42% (61/142)   
Resolving deltas:  44% (63/142)   
Resolving deltas:  54% (78/142)   
Resolving deltas:  64% (91/142)   
Resolving deltas:  65% (93/142)   
Resolving deltas:  68% (97/142)   
Resolving deltas:  70% (100/142)   
Resolving deltas:  72% (103/142)   
Resolving deltas:  73% (105/142)   
Resolving deltas:  74% (106/142)   
Resolving deltas:  75% (107/142)   
Resolving deltas:  76% (108/142)   
Resolving deltas:  80% (115/142)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (142/142)   
Resolving deltas: 100% (142/142), done.
13:29:45.100982 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Checking connectivity'
13:29:45.116984 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' '--progress=Checking connectivity'
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host github.com: 0xce60d0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host github.com
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.112) port 443 (#1)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'b7d881bfd1412bb946280eca716fa19050e9f1c2'
> POST /echosys/CSE340cpp.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
Authorization: Basic [redacted]
User-Agent: git/2.11.0.windows.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 325

* upload completely sent off: 325 out of 325 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: GitHub Babel 2.0
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-GitHub-Request-Id: CA15:33E9:3D30FB2:5714314:59EFA2A9
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #1 to host github.com left intact
error: unable to create file Pj2/Icon
: Invalid argument
error: unable to create file Pj2/v0/Icon
: Invalid argument
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'

2017-10-24 13:29:45.2660|INFO|thread:15|DashboardViewModel|Selected repository 'echosys/bonjour_proj'
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 84 at GitClient.cs:195
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread:25|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 84 at GitClient.cs:195 after waiting 3.53E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 85 at RepositoryModel.cs:596
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread:44|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 85 at RepositoryModel.cs:596 after waiting 1.25E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread:11|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 86 at GitClient.cs:267
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread:11|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 85 at RepositoryModel.cs:596 after blocking 0.0035651s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2835|INFO|thread:11|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 86 at GitClient.cs:267 after waiting 0.0003029s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2925|INFO|thread:11|GitEnvironment|Process set up with this SSH Agent info: 7136:/tmp/ssh-klrBWqcAJASj/agent.1820
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2925|INFO|thread:11|GitEnvironment|PATH is F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\share\git-tfs;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\R88BMX93.5ZB\4QNCR5ZP.PEG\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0003_5794af8169eeff14;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\lfs-amd64_1.5.5;F:\Windows\System32;F:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\;F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2925|INFO|thread:11|ProcessWrapper|Starting: Process - FileName: 'F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd\git.exe', Args: 'status --untracked-files=all --porcelain -z ', Working Directory: G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj\
2017-10-24 13:29:45.2925|INFO|thread:43|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 84 at GitClient.cs:195 after blocking 0.0129733s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.3585|INFO|thread:39|ConcurrentRepositoryConnection|Took 64ms to git status
2017-10-24 13:29:45.3585|INFO|thread:39|ConcurrentRepositoryConnection|Took 64ms to git status and parse output
2017-10-24 13:29:45.3585|INFO|thread:39|NewCommitViewModel|Took 72ms to load files for G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj
2017-10-24 13:29:45.3585|INFO|thread:39|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 86 at GitClient.cs:267 after blocking 0.0718155s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.5590|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 87 at OpenInExistingProgramViewModel.cs:266
2017-10-24 13:29:45.5590|INFO|thread:30|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 87 at OpenInExistingProgramViewModel.cs:266 after waiting 4.48E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.5590|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 88 at GitClient.cs:588
2017-10-24 13:29:45.5590|INFO|thread:48|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 88 at GitClient.cs:588 after waiting 5.2E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.5590|INFO|thread:42|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 88 at GitClient.cs:588 after blocking 0.0018408s
2017-10-24 13:29:45.6285|INFO|thread: 5|OpenInExistingProgramViewModel|Took 69ms to load solution files at G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj
2017-10-24 13:29:45.6285|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 87 at OpenInExistingProgramViewModel.cs:266 after blocking 0.0690201s
2017-10-24 13:29:46.2051|INFO|thread: 1|NewCommitViewModel|Took 845ms to render file list for G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj
2017-10-24 13:29:46.2051|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 89 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:319
2017-10-24 13:29:46.2051|INFO|thread:30|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 89 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:319 after waiting 4.18E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:46.2181|INFO|thread:10|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 89 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:319 after blocking 0.0104839s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.2803|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 90 at GitClient.cs:195
2017-10-24 13:29:48.2803|INFO|thread:39|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 90 at GitClient.cs:195 after waiting 6E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.2803|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 91 at RepositoryModel.cs:596
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3088|INFO|thread:25|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 91 at RepositoryModel.cs:596 after waiting 0.0283676s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3088|INFO|thread:27|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 92 at GitClient.cs:267
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3088|INFO|thread:44|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 92 at GitClient.cs:267 after waiting 5.66E-05s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3088|INFO|thread:27|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 91 at RepositoryModel.cs:596 after blocking 0.00484s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3088|INFO|thread: 5|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 90 at GitClient.cs:195 after blocking 0.0359212s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3183|INFO|thread:11|GitEnvironment|Process set up with this SSH Agent info: 7136:/tmp/ssh-klrBWqcAJASj/agent.1820
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3183|INFO|thread:11|GitEnvironment|PATH is F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\share\git-tfs;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\R88BMX93.5ZB\4QNCR5ZP.PEG\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0003.0003_5794af8169eeff14;F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\lfs-amd64_1.5.5;F:\Windows\System32;F:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\;F:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\x64
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3183|INFO|thread:11|ProcessWrapper|Starting: Process - FileName: 'F:\Users\Jean_Claude\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd\git.exe', Args: 'status --untracked-files=all --porcelain -z ', Working Directory: G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj\
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread:48|ConcurrentRepositoryConnection|Took 65ms to git status
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread:48|ConcurrentRepositoryConnection|Took 65ms to git status and parse output
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread:48|NewCommitViewModel|Took 73ms to load files for G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread:48|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Released concurrent scheduler for operation: 92 at GitClient.cs:267 after blocking 0.0734329s
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread: 1|NewCommitViewModel|Took 0ms to render file list for G:\GitHub\bonjour_proj
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread: 1|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquiring concurrent scheduler for operation 93 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:319
2017-10-24 13:29:48.3853|INFO|thread:27|AsyncReaderWriterLock|Acquired concurrent scheduler for operation: 93 at RepositoryViewModel.cs:319 after waiting 1.74E-05s
```